# How to contact an emergency service using only Internet?

Tags: internet, website

Suppose you are apart from the mobile or whatever phone (so can't call 112 or 911 or 999), but have have access to a computer with internet connection.

How do you call/message an emergency service (of whatever country in hope they will route the request to the correct destination) using only Internet?

Maybe there's some 911-like website or public SIP or whatever? Or better go to some chat/forum/StackExchange/whatever and ask somebody to make a call for you? (will users really believe?)

/* 1. I'm not in any emergency, just curious. 2. I'm not sure on what SE site to ask this question. */

Comment: `I'm not in emergency`, that line was really needed... :-)

Comment: "call 911 with Skype or any other VoIP application" -> Can I really call outside the Internet unless I paid something somewhere?

Comment: "Internet is really too open as a communication channel for serious things like emergency calls." -> It can be frustrating if fire blocked way to everything while you working on computer, and others in some online chat only making fun of you instead of calling the help...

Comment: I think @MarioDeSchaepmeester is right. Also, there is a major problem with location when using emergency services over the internet. [Regarding Skype and Emergency Services](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/legal/emergency/) & [VoIP and 911 in general](http://voip.about.com/od/servicesandsolutions/a/got911.htm)

Comment: So thinking up the answer based on the above comment and my suggestions.

Comment: @amiregelz, I expect if you reached _some_ emergency service then the half of business done and they should contact the correct service. Am I wrong?

Comment: I wonder if there isn't a TTD service that could be utilized for this?

Comment: What is TTD here? Wikipedia gives multiple unrelated acronyms.

Comment: 'Unfriended: The Dark Web' & 'The Den' highlight the need for access to emergency services without a voice phone. Sadly this question is closed, without regard to the need for emergency services.